# How can I connect users and courses using Moodle database?

Tags: moodle

I was doing a small project with Moodle, and I have a little query a more advanced.

I would like to be able to create a course by means of a SQL query in the Moodle DB and to be able to link it to an existing user in Moodle.

Has anyone ever done something like this and can you give me your opinion suggestion?

I am using Moodle version 3.10 dev

Thanks a lot.

Comment: if you are trying to make duplication of course with existing enrolled users, then you can use moodle course export and import features.

Answer (score 0):

What don’t you want to use the moodle api will be easy and best way to get what you need done.

You just need to make 2 api calls create course and enroll user .

Answer (score 0):

You need to use moodle APIs or native functions in order to create courses or users. In this case SQL is not a common practice and need to be avoided.

Instead, you may need to use core functions, API etc. In example:

```
#create a course
$course = create_course($data, $editoroptions = NULL); 

#or get course if it already exists
$course = get_course($courseid);

#enrol student
$enrol_manual   = enrol_get_plugin('manual');

$enrolinstances = enrol_get_instances($course->id, true);

foreach($enrolinstances as $instance) {
   
   #enrol user
   $enrol_manual->enrol_user($instance, $studentid);
   break;

}
```

Check these guides as well:

- https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Enrolment_API
- https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Core_APIs
- https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Access_API